# Unexpected identifier when using bcrypt

Tags: javascript, bcrypt

```
await bcrypt.compare(password, element.Password)
```

This line gives an saying "Unexpected identifier". I have already installed bcrypt using

1) Powershell:

> npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

2) NPM

> npm install bcrypt

Comment: Installing isn't enough. You need to `require`. Did you do that, too?

Comment: Did you require bcrypt?

Comment: Most probably you have are calling this function within a callback that is not async. The outer function maybe async but the callback is not.

Comment: Please provide a completed test case.

Answer (score 2):

The function enclosing `await bcrypt.compare(password, element.Password)` must be declared `async`:

```
const aFunction = async (password) => {
  // ...
  await bcrypt.compare(password, element.Password)
}
```